Combining PCA Results of Multiple Imputed Datasets Using Generalized Procrustes Analysis
I have a large dataset containing many different variables. My final aim is to create a composite index based on a subset of these variables, where their relative weights are determined by a principal component analysis. However, since my dataset contained quite a lot of NA values, I used, among others, multiple imputation. I have ran my PCA results on each of the imputed datasets separately, but now want to pool my results so I can come to a more general conclusion.
The issue I am facing is that the pool() function contained in MICE does not like working with PCA. I cannot seem to get it to work, no matter how hard I try and after having looked around on the internet for a long time. My second best solution is to use the approach suggested by Van Ginkel (2023), namely Generalized Procrustes Analysis. Here, I am using the same FactoMineR package which I also use for PCA, and which includes the GPA() function.
However, all my efforts fail because of GPA asking for a group, and me being unable to find out what group it wants. I have read the documentation on GPA, which is not very helpful in this regard. Moreover, I can find no examples online which show me what I should use as a group
Does anyone have experience with FactoMineR's GPA() function (preferably in combination with PCA) and is able to tell me how to pool my PCA results?
